# SVG CSS Animation draw and erase on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg, css-animations

I am trying to create a menu opening and closing animation by drawing a circle/donut SVG shape, displaying some icons and then I would it too undraw (I know thats not a real word, but it best fits the description)/erase the shape and hide the icons when the menu is closed.

I have gotten as far as drawing the shape and displaying the icons when the button is opened, but no matter what I have tried, when I try to erase/undraw it, it just disapears.

Secondly, if you then click to open the menu again, it doesnt do the animation the second time round.

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v4hw87nc/4/) of what I have achieved so far! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 .circle_animation {
  stroke-dasharray: 377;
  stroke-dashoffset: 377;
}

.circle_animation {
    -webkit-animation: MenuOpened 1s ease-out forwards;
    animation: MenuOpened 1s ease-out forwards;    
}


@-webkit-keyframes MenuOpened {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes MenuOpened {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes MenuClosed {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 377;
  }
}

@keyframes MenuClosed {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 377;
  }
}
```

Thanks

Anton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

The one that was causing you the main problems is this line:

```
$(".MenuSVG").hide();
```

which is causing your SVG to be hidden as soon as you click the close button.  So you won't get to see the "un-draw" animation.

I think you meant:

```
setTimeout(function(){$(".MenuSVG").hide();}, 1000);
```

Once that is fixed, you can work out why the close animation doesn't work.

If you want to cheat, there is a working version here:

> https://jsfiddle.net/v4hw87nc/6/

Comment: Perfect! This fixed it. Thanks